# Does it cost to setup a custom domain on Heroku?

Tags: heroku

When attempting to add a custom domain to my Heroku application I am prompted to add my billing details.

Does this mean it costs to setup custom domains for Heroku, even on the free host packages?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To quote [Heroku](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/custom-domains):

> Domains can be added to both free and paid Heroku apps and adding domains does not incur extra charges. For verification purposes, you must verify your Heroku account to add domains to apps.